# Difficulties scrolling in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, typescript, ionic2

In my music app, some pages use large button-images that when pressed and held adds the sound to my favorites. The problem I am having is that since these button-images use the ionic (press) tag, it does not scroll when you press on a button and slide up/down. When you drag using the background (gray) and not the green buttons it works.

I think this can be resolved with CSS but I’m not sure how.

**tvsounds.ts**

```
<img src="{{ sound.imageUrl }}" (tap)="play(sound)" (press)="toggleFavourite(sound)" />
```

[image: two muppets]

Comment: Why do you use `press` event instead of `click` event?

Comment: Just use `(click)` instead of `(press)`. This should work.

Comment: Also, if not try using gestures in this : http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures

Comment: because when a user "clicks/taps" on the button it plays a sound. It does not make sense for it to save it to favorits just because a user played a sound. Thats why I use press